# Hide YouTube elements

Tags: youtube

PICTURES: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWMMH.jpg

Hello everyone, i need to know if it is possible to hide or delete this options for YouTube on my wordpress webpage:

1. YouTube title
2. Watch later
3. Share
4. End related videos
5. 360º Spherical control
6. More videos on paused

I tried to modify with css but does not recognize any style. And some embed codes neither recognizes them.

Answer (score 0):

As per the image that i saw , it seems like you are trying to cross bridge the you tube security layer that doesn't let any one to do modification with youtube DOM.

Best Solution is to take a premium subscription ,Then No user control element will be show up on screen .

you can't do interruption in you tube media player.

or choose youtube developer mode here is  the [Link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/package-summary)

Comment: Hello @omesh thanks for ur respond. A shame that cannot be modified :(

Comment: Hello @Martin Hope you got the answer from the developer guide link